# Restart of docker service 1 should restart service 2 and service 3

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

How would you recommend achieving the restart of both `service2` and `service3` when `service1` stops and restarts in Docker compose ?

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    image: your_image1
    restart: always

  service2:
    image: your_image2
    restart: always
   
     

  service3:
    image: your_image3
    restart: always
```

Comment: you'll have to do that manually afaik `docker compose restart [service-name]` or `docker-compose restart [service-name]` if you're on V1

Comment: If you have such tight coupling between your containers, then containers are a bad fit for your code

Comment: I have a scenario where I put a certificate yearly once in a folder in that case I want those container to restart automatically. Certificate is uploaded from service 1. So service 2 and service 3 and service 1 needs a restart

Comment: You probably have a script / way to invoke the change of certificate. Just extend it with @AnadiMisra 's answer, to restart the services after you have replaced the cert. (On the host machine side) instead solving it through out containers itself.